# ModalViewController dimensions on orientation change

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation, modalviewcontroller, dimensions

I have set `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` in `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method.
When I present `UIModalViewController` I always get dimensions of the view 748 x 1024 regardless of the screen rotation. If I rotate the screen, dimensions does not get updated and are the same in portrait and landscape mode: 748 x 1024.

This is the code to present modal view:

```
MyModalViewController *myModal = [[MyModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:myModal animated:YES];
```

MyModalViewController extends another MyCUSTOMViewController which is a subclass of `UIViewController`:

```
@interface MyModalViewController : MyCUSTOMViewController

@interface MyCUSTOMViewController : UIViewController
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have read there are a couple of things to consider:

1. To make other orientations available throughout the app, you must override `-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window` within the app’s **`UIApplicationDelegate`**, and return **`UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`**:
2. In your custom viewcontroller you need to override two methods:

> ```
> - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
> {
>     return YES;
> }
>
> - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
> {
>     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
> }
> ```

Comment: actually which dimensions are u referring to? the frame ? the bounds?

Comment: OMFG. You are right. I was referring to frame dimensions not bounds. That's why I get wrong dimensions. But I am not quite sure what is that? Isn't the view's bellow modalView also rotating ? Thanks!